# Доступ к полям объектов в ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, коллекции

Здравствуйте! Я добавляю в ArrayList два объекта. Как можно получить доступ к их полям?

```
ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();
Test test = new Test();
Test2 test2 = new Test2();

arraylist.Add(test);
arraylist.Add(test2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуясь (давно устаревшим) `ArrayList`, вы теряете информацию о типах положенных в него объектов. Поэтому вам придётся делать явный cast с риском ошибиться и не угадать нужный тип.

Скорее всего, вам нужен типизированный `List<Test>`. В вашем примере вы записываете в список два разнородных объекта; скорее всего, вам это не нужно, вам нужно либо несколько отдельных списков, либо просто отдельные переменные (либо один из типов является подтипом другого).

Comment: Ну по заданию, у меня есть класс, от которого наследуются еще 6. И объекты этих 6 классов мне надо поместить в коллекцию. Можно ли это как-нибудь осуществить? Пример я привел для краткой сути того, что мне надо.

Comment: @SlowAR: Заведите `List<T>`, где `T` — тип общего предка.

Comment: Я пробовал так делать, но в итоге имею доступ к полям только общего предка

Comment: @SlowAR: Разумеется. А как может быть иначе? Если `list[i]` может быть любого производного типа, как компилятор может знать, какие из полей производного класса там есть? И как вы можете это знать?

---
Расскажите, зачем вам доступ к полям конкретных классов в списке.

Comment: ну, например, чтобы занести в поле другое значение

Comment: @SlowAR: А как вы знаете, что объект нужного типа? Приведите пример кода, который будет работать со списком.

Comment: Ну понял в принципе. Реализую немного по-другому. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Использовать в типизированной коллекции можно так:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string GetAbout()
    {
        return "I'm BaseClass";
    }
}
```

//======================================================

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return this.Age;
    }

    public override string GetAbout()
    {
        return "I'm InheritedClass";
    }
}
```

//======================================================

```
List<BaseClass> collect = new List<BaseClass>();

collect.Add(new InheritedClass());
collect.Add(new BaseClass());

foreach(var item in collect)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetAbout());

    var inheritedItem = item as InheritedClass;

    if(inheritedItem != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inheritedItem.GetAge());
    }
}
```